# Blazor WASM, EditForm not validating

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to validate an Email, using an EditForm, there is no errors and i cannot see anything using breakpoints.
It should not go into the method EnteredMail(), if the input field is empty, but it still does, it does not show the error message either?

The EditForm that it should validate on

```
        <EditForm Model="Email" OnValidSubmit="EnteredEmail">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />

            <label>Indtast emailen tilknyttet din konto</label>
            <InputText placeholder="Email" @bind-Value="Email" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Email)" />

            <button type="submit">Næste</button>
        </EditForm>
```

And the property, where to DataAnnotation / Attribute is.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dette felt skal udfyldes.")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = String.Empty;
```

I have tried to create a seperate class for it, tried to validate the form myself (It returns true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why your code does not work. I guess because

> <EditForm Model="Email

does not work with string.

However using a class works:

```
<EditForm Model="myClass" OnValidSubmit="EnteredEmail">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <label>Indtast emailen tilknyttet din konto</label>
    <InputText placeholder="Email" @bind-Value="myClass.Email" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => myClass.Email)" />

    <button type="submit">Næste</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    private void EnteredEmail()
    {

    }
}
```

MyClass:

```
 public class MyClass
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dette felt skal udfyldes.")]
     public string Email { get; set; } = String.Empty;
 }
```

Comment: I've tried creating a class aswell, and it didn't work.. Atm im out of ideas

Comment: I have tested this code. If you do it the same way it should work.

Comment: I don't see why it did not work before when i made the class, i probably did something else that fucked it up.
But it seems to be working now, thanks :) !

Comment: Does it mean, that you HAVE to create a class for it to work in the EditForm?

Comment: i think yes at least the docs show it that way:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0